# How to check if a BroadCast Sender has a custom permission to send it

Tags: android, permissions, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I have a plugin for my app that is started with a BroadCast. I already managed to add a custom permission, so only apps with the permission can receive the broadcast.

However, I have no idea how to achieve the more important part: How can I check, if the sender has a custom permission, so only my main app can send the broadcast?

I know this is possible, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
Context ctx = ...;
int result = ctx.checkCallingPermission("your.permission.goes.here");
if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == result) {
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

in your broadcast receiver. Or declare the permission in your AndroidManifest.xml where you define your receiver.

```
<reciever android:name="your.receiver.goes.here"
    android:permission="your.permission.goes.here" />
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: AFAIK `checkCallingPermission()` will **NOT** work from `BroadcastReceiver`, because it is meant for use only in `Binder`.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried using checkCallingPermission from within an AppWidgetProvider and although I've added to the 
AndroidManifest.xml:

```
...
    <permission android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.PERSONAL_INFO"
      android:description="@string/receiveUpdates" android:protectionLevel="normal"
      android:label="@string/receiveStatusUpdates" android:name="my.prem.RCV_STATUS">
    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="my.prem.RCV_STATUS"/>
...
```

In my widget, result is -1 (PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED).

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   ... // check that this is the Action I've been waiting for.
   int result = context.checkCallingPermission(my.prem.RCV_STATUS);
   ....
}
```

Clicking on the widget sends a PendingIntent to start a services which performs an AsyncTask, the postExecute of the AsyncTask sends the Intent I'm waiting for.

Thanks.