# Context.checkCallingPermission checking always fails?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I'm encountering such a scenario in Android.
App `A` has permission `PERM` to get some information. Instead of directly getting this information, it sends an intent to one BroadCastReceiver inside App `B` (of course `B` has `PERM`). In order to ensure all such apps like `A` has the permission, I use a context.checkCallingPermission (with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8522090/528929)).

However it always fails.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String info;
    String perm = Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE;
    Log.i(TAG, "callPid="+ Binder.getCallingPid()+" myPid="+ Process.myPid()); /// SAME PID
    if (context.checkCallingPermission(perm) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i(TAG, "not granted " + perm);
        info = "denied perm " + perm;
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, perm + " already granted");
        info = dumpDeviceInfoImpl(context);
    }
}
```

Specially, the comment line always return SAME pid (`B`'s), when I send intent from `A`. I can confirm `A` and `B` have different PIDs.

**update**

Previously I was thinking it is due to `BroadCastReceiver`, so I tried to `startActivity` from `A` and then start an activity in `B`. Once again, during `checkCallingPermission`, it fails again. Surprisingly, still returning the SAME pid.

So what's the correct way to use `checkCallingPermission`?

Answer (score 0):

use this methdos

`checkCallingPermission(Context context, String permission, String packageName)`

Checks whether the IPC you are handling has a given permission and whether the app op that corresponds to this permission is allowed.

Comment: seems not working either, when i set packageName to `A`'s.